# javascript regular expression with multiple parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a javascript regex only matching NASM-style comments in HTML. For example, matching `"; interrupt"` for `"INT 21h ; interrupt"`.

You may know `/;.*/` can't be the answer because there can be a HTML entity before the comment; I thought `/(?:[^&]|&.+;)*(;.*)$/` should work for it, but I found it has two problems:

1. `"&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ; hello world".match(/(?:[^&]|&.+;)*(;.*)$/)` is an array `["&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ; hello world", "; hello world"]`. I don't want an array.
2. `"&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ; hello world; a message".match(/(?:[^&]|&.+;)*(;.*)$/)` is `["&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ; hello world; a message", "; a message"]`; even worse the second element.

Question:

1. Why is `(?:)` block returned?
2. Why `"; a message"`, not `"; hello world; a message"`?
3. What's the right regex I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ad 1.)
the `?:` block is not returned. instead, the complete match is returned in the first array element. this behavior follows the specification for non-global matching (ie. without `g` option).

ad 2.)
the first part of your regex (`(?:[^&]|&.+;)*`) matches too much. in fact it would match the complete line if you dropped the second portion. in plain english you asked to match a sequence of `&` followed by as many characters as possible followed by a `;`, or any symbol other than `&`, respectively, and you ask the engine to repeat this match as often as possible until the last `;` in the test string (if there is one).

ad 3.)
try

```
(?:[^&;]*(&[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+;[^&;]*)*)(;.*)$
```

it fixes the broken entity matching and returns the longest `;`-initial suffix.

tested with [pagecolumn regex tester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm) (i'm not affiliated with this website).

Comment: Thanks! After changing your example to `(?:[^&;]*(?:&[^\s;]+;[^&;]*)*)(;.*)$` to care entities like `&#xAC01;`, I decided to use `(?:[^&;]|&[^;\s]+;)*(;.*)$`.

Answer (score 1):

1) The (?:) is not being returned. What you are seeing is that the .match() method will *always* return an array: The first element is the whole match, and the following elements (if any) are the back-references. In this case, you have one back-reference, so the array contains two items.

2) Because of the first half of your regex:

```
(?:[^&]|&.+;)*
```

This is not a good idea! This will match just about *anything*, even including new lines! In fact, the **only** thing it won't match is a "&" that is not followed by a ";" on the same line. Thus, it is matching everything up to the last ";" in each of your lines.

3) I'm not at all familiar with MASM-style comments in HTML, so I'd need to see a more extensive list of what you want matched/not matched in order to confidently give a good answer here.

But here's something I've thrown together very quickly, to at least solve the two examples you gave above:

```
.*&.*?;\s(;.*)$
```

Comment: Thanks! While your example can not be adopted for general cases, mention on multiline was very helpful.